# Both updates (Windows and Office) are required?

Tags: windows, security, patch

Let's say I have a Windows 7 with Microsoft Office 2010. And I want to patch the vulnerability CVE-2017-0199.

The following article from Microsoft says that you need to install these 2 KB in my case (as I have this software):

- Microsoft Office 2010 (KB3141538) 64-Bit Edition
- Windows 7 x64 (KB4015546)

[Windows explanation of CVE-2017-0199](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0199)

The question is: should I install both patches? Or installing one of the above already solves the vulnerability for my system? I can't find any information about this. I'm interested in a kind of technical explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I install both patches?

You need to install **KB3141538** and instead of [KB4015546](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015546) you should installed [KB4022719](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4022719).

If you are not willing to install the [KB4022719](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4022719) you should install [KB4022722](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022722).  [KB4015546](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015546) is from April, while you could install that, you would still be vulerable to the exploits fixed in May and June.

> Or installing one of the above already solves the vulnerability for my
>   system?

[CVE-2017-0199](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0199) is a vulerability against Office.

> I'm interested in a kind of technical explanation to the question.

**You should install all available Office patches and install the Security Monthly Quality Rollup every month.**  The primary reason is, the exploit that made WannaCrypt possible, was fixed 2 months before the malware was even released.  The linked vulerability in question was fixed released back in April, which means you have been vulerable to that exploit, for over 2 months.

Comment: You should verify you have the current monthly rollup installed, if its already installed, then you have been patched.  I didn't bother to link to the May monthly rollup for obvious reasons, its an old patch, which has been superseded by the June monthly rollup.